# Find $G_a(x)$ for $a_n={4^{3n-5}\over3^{2n+4}}$

Tags: generating-functions

I don't really know where to begin on this one. I haven't gotten very far but I feel like with a few hints I should at least be able to start solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$$a_nx^n=\left(\frac{4^{-5}}{3^4}\right)\left(\frac{4^3x}{3^2}\right)^n.$$